# Back Button implementation without losing the current state of AACPlayer

Tags: android, back-button

in my application, I am going back and forth between two activities A and B.

in activity A user chooses listView content and,

in activity B user starts to listen shoutcast.

I am using an outside AACPlayer library with 2.2 SDK.

While going back to activity A, I didnot want to player paused or stopped, which I can manage to do.
However each time I go back to activity A from B, a new instance is started and if I press a new shoutcast they start to play at the same with the previous.

My question is, what should I do to come back to the current instance of the activity B.

My going back implementation is

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonBack:    
                Intent info = new Intent(getBaseContext(),index.class);
                info.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                HomeActivity.this.startActivity(info);
            break;
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using Static fields in activity A. I made the methods of AAC Player static.

```
static void startPlayingRadio(radioChannel radioChannel){ ... }
static void stopPlayingRadio(){ ... }   
static boolean isRadioPlaying(){ ... }
static boolean isRadioStopped(){ ... }
```

By this way I can start, stop or pause the radio player form activity B.

This is also much more correct in the sense of implementation. Because there suppose to be only one radio player.

Answer (score 0):

When you're going from activity A to B, could you pass a flag in with the Intent telling it whether to start a new song or not?  Of course, you may have to pass this flag back from B to A when the back button is pressed (depending on your code).

Comment: thanks for the quick response the problem is, when I come back to activity B, I lose the control. I mean the previous activity started to act like a background activity. what I want is to turn back to the previous activity rather than starting a new one. Each time I am going A to B I am starting a new intent, may this is what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, yes...since you are leaving activity B you cannot reconnect to that same activity.  What you need to do is create a Service that runs the media player.  Then you bind and unbind to this Service which will give you access to the media player functionality.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html